# How to extend C: drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ntfsresize

I have my Windows 8.1 installed on the primary C: drive and I want to extend its size from other free (unallocated) space. There are lots of solutions online but none of them is 100% correct or offer assurance of not losing data. I can't afford to lose any data. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Disk Management? There is no solution that can guarantee that you won't lose data. This is why you should always do backups.

Comment: There is never a guarantee that you will not lose data when tinkering with partitions, ALWAYS back up first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the Disk Management tool built-in to Windows 8.

To access, pressing the **Windows key** and **X**, to access the *Power User menu* and click on **Disk Management**. The window below will open:

[image: Windows 8 Disk Management]

From here you can select your disks and partition them as you want. Right clicking on the disk, over the various partitions, will give you the option of shrinking or expanding the partition.

[image: Expand/Shrink Menu]

However, as  *Rsya Studios* and *Moab* have stated in the comments, make sure that you back up your data before performing **any** changes to your partition/disk - just in case...

Comment: This is what I'd normally use. Unless the unallocated space is in front of the partition I want to extend (will not work with Disk Management) - in that case I use Gparted or EaseUS partition master.

Comment: I heartily agree that Disk Management will not work for empty space before the partition. I've not tried the two tools you've mentioned. I will give them a shot. I normally use _Partition Magic_.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in disk management has many limitations, don't extend partition when unallocated space on its left or unallocated space is non-adjacent. Basic partitions functions are totally OK for disk management.

If you want to increase system partition without losing data, suggest you try free 3rd partition tool and here is the youtube  guide which introduce in detail. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id-fIh15ED0